# AS3 modification to read text from array not from xml

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

Please help me to modify AS3 code to read text from array not from xml.

original code:

```
function readTheText() {
// Zeroing the TEXT
// ------------------------------------------
DisplayHolder.MultiLetters_MC.TheText = "";
// clear the previous interval
clearInterval(PhraseChange);
// ------------------------------------------
// Reading the text from the XML
// ------------------------------------------
for (i=0; i < NumOfLines; i++) {
    this["textLine"+i] = myXml.firstChild.childNodes[LinesCount].childNodes[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
    if (this["textLine"+i] == undefined){
        this["textLine"+i] = " ";
    }
    padLength = NumOfLettersInLine - this["textLine"+i].length;
    // Add padding if necessary
    if (padLength > 0){
        for (p=0; p < padLength; p++) {
            this["textLine"+i] += " ";
        }
    } else {
        // Subtract letters if necessary
        var theString:String = this["textLine"+i];
        var theSubString:String = theString.substring(0,NumOfLettersInLine);
        this["textLine"+i] = theSubString;
    }
    // Our final text
    DisplayHolder.MultiLetters_MC.TheText += this["textLine"+i];
}...
```

replace reading from xml with:

```html
    var group1:Array = ['DRIFT', 'FRESH&TONIC', 'SHIT ON GRASS', 'DOWNTOWN', 'AGED NEGRONI', 'FIREBALL', 'B5200', 'BLACK JACK', 'HOT WORM'];
var texts:Array = [];
```

best regards

Comment: I don't understand what's your problem, but if you want to read array elements you have just to use a `for` loop. Take a look on [working with arrays](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fdc.html) from help.adobe.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Replace `NumOfLines` with `group1.length`.
2. Replace `myXml.firstChild.childNodes[LinesCount].childNodes[i].firstChild.nodeValue;` with `group1[i];`